# Any way to speed up d3.csv on large files?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Many large CSV files can be significantly compressed using e.g. gzip. Is there any way to speed up D3 on large CSV files by reducing the amount of data that needs to be transferred across the internet to the javascript in the browser. For example, if I have a 30MB CSV file `foo.csv` that compresses to a 9MB foo.csv.gz file, can I communicate the smaller file and adjust D3 to decompress it before doing the rest of the `d3.csv` processing.

Answer (score 1):

No. D3 doesn't provide any functionality to handle compressed files. You could use a third-party library such as [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/), but then you won't be able to use `d3.csv` directly.

Comment: I looked at JSZip. One comment on

http://www.picurl.org/blog/2009/11/22/creating-zip-archives-with-gears/

was that "JSZip doesn’t perform any compression, it simply concatenates the string data and adds some information about the file organisation", so I guess the approach you suggest would be to gzip the csv file, use JSZip for communication, and then make some minor changes to d3.js. Is that right? Has anyone ever done that? I can't find anything on the web. Is it really possible?

Comment: You wouldn't need to change D3. First you get the data using AJAX or something like that, then decompress it and then pass it to the D3 function that will parse it. I'm not aware of anybody having tried this, but it should be possible. A better and easier solution however would be to simply switch on compression on your server so that the communication with the client is compressed automatically and transparently.